# Using dgCMatrix for kcca in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I am trying to use kernel canonical correlation analysis in R and its usage is:

```
**## S4 method for signature 'matrix'**
kcca(x, y, kernel="rbfdot", kpar=list(sigma=0.1),
     gamma = 0.1, ncomps = 10, ...)

Arguments
x a matrix containing data index by row
y a matrix containing data index by row
```

So my x and y matrices are very large and sparse, and they belong to class 'dgCMatrix' with 6 slots. I'm new to R and I'm confused as to how to use matrices from this class as input matrices to the kcca method.

When I use them as-is:

```
kcca(Data1_mat, Data2_mat, kernel="rbfdot", kpar=list(sigma=0.1),
     gamma = 0.1, ncomps = 10)
```

I get this error: 
Error in x * x : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming function `kcca` comes from package `kernlab`, from the documentation I gather that `kcca` requires normal dense matrices and that it doesn't accept sparse matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed:  `kcca()` from package `kernlab`  currently can only work with traditional R matrices (which are *dense*).

Some inspection of the code, and one example do suggest that indeed, not too many changes may be needed and enhance the `kernlab` package to also work with sparseMatrix objects from the Matrix package.

Notably `drop0(zapsmall( <mat> ) )`  can be used to make the "kernelMatrix" objects themselves to be sparse.